# How to change Prettier behaviour on .less Files?

Tags: formatting, less, visual-studio-code, lint, prettier

I am using Visual Studio Code and [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) in my Typescript project. It also formats [less](http://lesscss.org/) files.

**What prettier does is putting every selector on a single line..**

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4... {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Ends up as a very loooooooooooooong chain of selectors:**

```css
body,
div,
dl,
dt,
...
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**What I would like Prettier is, to just leave me alone (on this specific aspect. in `.less` files.) Keep them in a line (or several) if I wanted to. Or on multiple, if that is, what he finds:**

```css
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4... {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul,
ol {
    list-style: none;
}
```

**Btw:** I can „prove“, that only prettier has a hand in this, not any built-in stuff in vscode or my tslint, by putting a `// prettier-ignore` line before those selectors. That would also be a local fix, but I want a more general solution... without having to throw anti-linter comments at all of this...)

### update:

Maybe the solution is somewhere near pointing `.less` files to a different parser. However I can't find a single piece of sample code, how to tell prettier my postcss-Preferences then...

```css
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 140,
    "overrides": [{
        "files": "*.less",
        "options": {
            "parser": "postcss"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to prevent prettier from adding newlines to your selector list.  There is a prettier-stylelint integration coming to vscode though, see [support for prettier-stylelint  in vscode.](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/pull/218)

[Stylelint extension for vsCode](https://github.com/shinnn/vscode-stylelint) does have the option you need.  [newlines in selector lists : stylelint rule](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/selector-list-comma-newline-before/README.md).

> selector-list-comma-newline-before : 
>   "never-multi-line"

So you could just use stylelint instead of prettier.  Or wait for the PR on the prettier-stlelint integration.  It looks like it is very close.

Comment: Ah, think I need a moment to wrap my head around & test this:  So [prettier-stylelint](https://github.com/hugomrdias/prettier-stylelint) puts lint on top (alias 'afterwards') prettier?

Comment: Yes, it will.  In stylelint-fix mode.  I "assume" you could define a rule, like the selector-list one above, and have that apply even though prettier doesn't like it because stylelint is last but we will see about that. But they only mention excluding conflicting stylelint rules not the other way around.  prettier is quite opinionated

Comment: @mark spent a couple of hours wrapping my head around this. Although my problem was a bit different but this would give you an idea on how to setup stylelint with prettier in VSCode:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757106/3331700