# How to Edit Auto-Formatting Rules for CSS/SCSS/LESS using Prettier in VSCode?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, prettier

### Background:

I'm using [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension for VSCode to auto-format my code on save.

### Problem:

I'm used to writing single-line blocks in my sass files (where there's only a single property) i.e.

`.some-class { background: #f00; }`

Problem is the [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension formats it to multi-lines i.e.

```
.some-class {
    background: #f00;
}
```

It seems prettier uses stylelint for css/scss files and I've found these settings can be over-written by enabling this in the settings:

`"prettier.requireConfig": true` and using a **.prettierrc.js** file but haven't been able to turn-off linting for single-line blocks. Would appreciate, if anybody here has any fixes for this.

Thanks

### Update:

The settings can't be over-written by `"prettier.requireConfig": true`. The [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension for VSCode doesn't have an option to edit stylesheets linting from VSCode Settings.

However, there is an option to enable [stylelint](https://stylelint.io) integration but this requires **stylelint** and **stylelint-prettier npm modules**.

[Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) by default uses [standard stylelint configuration](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/rules.md) for stylesheet linting and formatting.

**Posted the solution below.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Solution:

In order to allow single-line blocks in VSCode using [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension, please take the following steps:

1. Enable stylelint integration by adding this in the VSCode Settings (JSON): `"prettier.stylelintIntegration": true`
2. Install **stylelint** and **stylelint-prettier** npm modules in your project directory. `npm install stylelint stylelint-prettier --save-dev`
3. Add a **.stylelintrc.json** file at the root of your project directory with the following code:

```
    {
        "plugins": ["stylelint-prettier"],
        "rules": {
            "block-closing-brace-newline-after": "always-multi-line",
            "block-closing-brace-empty-line-before": "never",
            "block-closing-brace-space-before": "always",
            "block-opening-brace-space-after": "always",
            "block-opening-brace-space-before": "always",
            "block-closing-brace-newline-before": "always-multi-line",
            "block-opening-brace-newline-after": "always-multi-line",
            "indentation": 4
        }
    }
```

You can add/customize more stylelint rules, see the [entire list of rules here](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/rules.md).

Took me a while to understand how to configure these options, if you're starting out with stylelint, I highly recommend you [read its guidelines first](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/about-rules.md).

Comment: Update for Oct 2019: it seems you don't have to update the VSCode settings anymore.

Comment: Prettier 3 have some changes. Please see changelog and consider to update your answer

Comment: `stylelintIntegration` is no longer supported :(

Answer (score -2):

I haven't known that vscode have that feature. One simple solution probably by specifying `prettier-ignore`?

```
/* prettier-ignore */
.some-class { background: #f00; }
```

Reference:

- https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#css

Comment: This doesn't work. Still formats. Also, not useful when there's multiple lines. I'm looking whether there's an option in prettier (in vscode) to use stylelint formatting rules

Answer (score -3):

How to configure Visual Studio Code to format css/scss/less files:

1. Install Prettier extension
2. Open a css/scss/less file in visual studio
3. Press ctrl + p on your keyboard
4. VS will ask you to configure a tool to indent these files
5. Select Prettier from the list